# Retrieve Current Drupal Theme?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Within the context of a module, how can you determine what theme is loaded for the current user?

```
drupal_get_path
path_to_theme
```

Neither of these are any good because they seem to only work in the template.php of a theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If users are allowed to select a theme for themselves, the theme they selected is saved in `$user->theme`, where `$user` is the user object.
The global variable `$custom_theme` contains the name of the theme currently set, if a module has set a custom theme.

The following snippet saves in `$current_theme` the name of the theme currently active:

```
global $custom_theme, $theme, $user;

if (!empty($user->theme)) {
  $current_theme = $user->theme;
}
elseif (!empty($custom_theme)) {
  $current_theme = $custom_theme;
}
else {
  $current_theme = $theme ? $theme : variable_get('theme_default', 'garland');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`path_to_theme` should work just fine, I tested it on two Drupal installs, and both worked. If the theme has not been initialized yet, `path_to_theme` will do that, which is what Drupal uses internally to set different global theme variables like `$theme_path`, which is the variable you are looking for.

Comment: Hm, that gave me the module path when I tried it a few days ago

Comment: @googletorp, nope - it depends upon the scope when `path_to_theme()` is called. From the docs: > when invoked within the scope of a theming call it will depend on
> where the theming function is handled. If implemented from a module,
> it will point to the module. If implemented from the active theme, it
> will point to the active theme >Source: [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/6)